# Testing the login functionality for Flask

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

```
from flask import session
from app import app


class loginTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    # Test to check if login i s set up correctly

    def setUp(self):
        # creates  a test client
        self.app = app.test_client()
        app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
        # propagate exceptions to the test client
        self.app.testing = True

    def test_login(self):
        # Test the login functionality
        with app.test_client() as client:
            rv = client.post('/register', data=dict(
                username="sendi",
                password="123456789"
            ), follow_redirects=True)

            rv1 = client.post('/login', data=dict(
                username="sendi",
                password="123456789"), follow_redirects=True)
```

---

My test fails between these two horizontal lines and i don't know what is causing it

```
        **logged_in = session["logged_in"]
        user_loggedin = session['logged_in']['username']
        users = session['users']
        user = users.items()**
```

---

```
        # test that when post request is successful
        self.assertEqual(
            rv.status_code, 200,
            "The sign up page was not loaded as expected")
        self.assertEqual(
            rv1.status_code, 200,
            "The login page was not loaded as expected")
        # test that the user is added to the session
        self.assertNotEqual(None, logged_in,
                            "The user was not logged in")

        # test that the username is in session
        self.assertEqual('sendi', user_loggedin, 'username not in session')
```

This is what i get in the console
self =

```
def test_login(self):
    # Test the login functionality
    with app.test_client() as client:
        rv = client.post('/register', data=dict(
            username="sendi",
            password="123456789"
        ), follow_redirects=True)

        rv1 = client.post('/login', data=dict(
            username="sendi",
            password="123456789"), follow_redirects=True)

        logged_in = session["logged_in"]
```

> ```
>       user_loggedin = session['logged_in']['username']
> ```
>
> E           TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

test_login.py:32: TypeError
========================== 1 failed in 3.02 seconds ===========================

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `session["logged_in"]` may be `None`. Attempting to index into None will raise that error.

To fix this, I would use `logged_in = session.get('logged_in', {})`. And then `user_loggedin = logged_in.get('username', None)`.  Then assert `self.assertNotEqual(logged_in, {})`